# Javascript array gets sorted before sort statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

Edit: This seems related to the way the chrome console handles object evaluation as noted by
jsN00b

[original here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects)

I'm sorting an array by name and then by age, logging the array three times:
Once right after initialization,
second and third time is after sorting the array by name and then age respectively.

The first `console.log()` call however, prints the array in its sorted state, but what I expected to have is the array in it's unsorted state.

Not sure if this is related to the way JavaScript handles array in memory or is is it a bug?

**Code:**

```js
function byField(field) {
  return (objA, objB) => (objA[field] > objB[field] ? 1 : -1);
}

let users = [
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
];

console.log(users);
users.sort(byField("name"));
console.log(users);
users.sort(byField("age"));
console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Expected output:**

```
//unsorted
[
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
];

//by name
[
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
];

//by age
[
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
];
```

**Actual Output:**

```
//unsorted
[
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
];

//by name
[
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
];

//by age
[
  { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
  { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
];
```

Comment: I've placed the original code into a snippet. When executing as a snippet the order of the first console remains exactly how the array is populated - which is expected. Arrays are expected to retain the order. So, if we set an array as :`[1, 3, 2]`, unless it is changed, the order will be retained (per my admittedly noob-ish understanding).

Comment: function byField(field) {
    return (objA, objB) => (objA[field] > objB[field] ? 1 : -1);
  }

  let users = [
    { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
    { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
    { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" },
  ];

  const sortedusers = users.sort(byField("name"));
  console.log(sortedusers);
  //if you want to age sort use this code
  const sortedusersage = users.sort(byField("age"));
  console.log(sortedusersage);

Answer (score 0):

Method `Array.prototype.sort` does mutate your initial array. For fix this problem you need to create copy of array and then sort this copy.
It is like follow example:

```
[...users].sort(byField("name"));
```